# Did they build a helipad just for the movie?

Tags: production, star-wars, film-location, the-last-jedi

There is a nice [featurette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ye6GCY_vqYk) of the new movie The Last Jedi from the Star Wars franchise. One shot (1:32) shows a helipad in the background. Did they build a helipad just for the movie and where is the helipad? I seem to recall that there was construction for one set, but I can't find any information.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Most of the scenes on [Ahch-To](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahch-To) were filmed on a real island in County Kerry of Ireland, called [Skellig Michael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellig_Michael).

[According to The Irish Times](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/environment/essential-renovation-works-to-begin-on-skellig-michael-1.1613506), the island has had a helipad since 1969.

So **no, they didn't need to build it.** It had already been there for several decades.

Comment: That helipad looks pretty worn, so makes sense it isn't new.